# Why default FCM notification occur?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am working with FCM code so, Notification work perfect but my question is whenever My app is in foreground that time it is displaying icons but if my app is in background or not open that time, it is displaying blank white icons.

so for the shake checking purpose below code i commented notify method of notification builder though Notification occur why?

```
              Notification notificationBuilder = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.brandlogo)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#126eb5"))//#126eb5
                .setLargeIcon(result)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))

                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


        int smallIconId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());
        if (smallIconId != 0) {
            if (notificationBuilder.contentView != null) {
                              notificationBuilder.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);           
        //notificationManager.notify(NCount++, notificationBuilder);
```

Comment: Answer given in this link.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when your app on the background or killed at that time android handle notification by own so solving this problem you need to set a default icon in your manifest.

add below snipped on your manifest file and set your default icon

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/your_notification_icon_here" />
```